# Using the :nth-child pseudo class, is it possible to select groups of 3 elements separated by groups of 2 elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm building a masonry grid and am having trouble figuring out the algebra to select the appropriate elements.

- Elements for 2x wide styles: **1, 7, 11, 17, 21, 27, ...**
- Elements for 2x high styles: **2, 6, 12, 16, 22, 26, ...**

All other elements will be handled by the default styles.

The markup is:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I can't quite find the pattern to use for my `:first-child` pseudo-classes. I've attached an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

Any math wizards up for the [likely very simple] challenge?

[image: grid]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can classify the sequences like this:

- 1, 7, 11, 17, 21, 27, ... contains 2 child sequences:

  - 1, 11, 21, ...
  - 7, 17, 27, ...

So we can use 2 selectors: `:nth-child(10n + 1)` and `:nth-child(10n + 7)`.

- 2, 6, 12, 16, 22, 26, ... contains 2 child sequences:

  - 2, 12, 22, ...
  - 6, 16, 26, ...

So we can use 2 selectors: `:nth-child(10n + 2)` and `:nth-child(10n + 6)`.

Based on your image, I can see that all the `1, 11, 21, ...`  and `7, 17, 27, ...` should have width of ***about*** `66.66%` (2/3) and a larger `height` compared with default height of other cells.All the `2, 12, 22, ...` and `6, 16, 26, ...` should have height the same with the `1, 11, 21, ...` and `7, 17, 27, ...` and they have the same width with the other default cells (about `33.33%` or `1/3`).

So we can style the `ul` like this:

```
ul {
  width:500px; 
  list-style:none;
  border:20px solid gray;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:0;
}
ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:33.33%;
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid lightgray;
  box-sizing:border-box;  
  text-align:center;
}
/* this is just to center the text vertically */
ul > li:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
ul > li:nth-child(10n + 1), ul > li:nth-child(10n + 7) {
  width:66.66%;
  height:80px;
}
ul > li:nth-child(10n + 2), ul > li:nth-child(10n + 6){
  height:80px;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/EcPex/2/)

In the demo above, you can see there is an inner border of `2px` around all the inner items and adjacent to the border of `ul`, to remove it you need to target the appropriate cells and remove the appropriate border. Here is the **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EcPex/3/)** which is more complicated.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for. I just couldn't recognize the sequences inside each set, so thank you for pointing them out!